# Very fine wax in Mead

Tags: techniques, mead, process

Was given a 1/2 bucket of crystalized honey and so made Mead.
Used Champagne yeast, Original Gravity 1.092, Final Gravity 0.996.

My sort of problem is : there seems to be a 'sediment'.  AT THE TOP!
After racking, the mead is clearing from the bottom upwards!

I assume this is beeswax, very fine, and so will turn in a sort of reverse Champagne treatment removing the wax/scum with a suction tube (turkey baster?)

Any comments please.

Answer (score 1):

Next time you rack, you should be able to position the racking cane/tube just above the sediment but below the floating wax. The wax should continue to float during the process.  Stop transferring when the wax starts to enter the tube.

In a primary/bottling bucket, I would just scoop it out or use a strainer/filter.